# Threre is no package TTR but I can see it

Tags: r

I have some code and when I include the TTR library

```
library(TTR)
```

I get this error

```
Error in library(TTR) : there is no package called ‘TTR’
```

but i can see the package here:

```
C:\Users\me\Docs\R-3.1.2\library\TTR
```

when I try to install the package again I get

```
install.packages("TTR")

package ‘TTR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘TTR’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMX19DB\downloaded_packages
```

Any idea how to fix? It looked like it didn't download to  C:\Users\me\Docs\R-3.1.2\library\

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/me/Docs/R-3.1.2/library"
```

COMMENT:  I recently modified the quantmod package but test that and it works. I only changed 2 lines and rebuilt it but I am not sure if that is the cause here.

Comment: Can you do a `sessionInfo()` and tell us what R version you are running?

Comment: R can only find packages in locations listed in `.libPaths()`. What does that return for you?

Comment: The Warning, "cannot remove prior installation of package ‘TTR’" is a significant hint. You may have the top-level folder in `C:\Users\me\Docs\R-3.1.2\library\TTR`, but the contents of that folder could be corrupt.  Make sure you close all R sessions that have loaded/attached TTR before you call `install.packages`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try what @Joshua Ulrich said first. I got the same issue so I just installed using the canonical form from CRAN.

```
install.packages("https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=TTR")
library(TTR)
```